# Assigning new values based on the field calculator and "case when then" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, error

I would like to do conditioning in the attribute table consisting of the following action:

```
CASE WHEN  "network" = icn_ref THEN '001|' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN  "network" = ncn THEN '001|' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN  "network" = rcn THEN '001|' ELSE '' END
|| CASE WHEN  "network" = lcn_ref THEN '002|' ELSE '' END
```

So I would like to create a field with only the values 001 and 002 depending on what value is currently in the "network" field.
However, when I create such an action in the field calculator, it only gets an error or 00 or null. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: i using QGIS  3.28

Comment: A case expression should have only one ELSE and only one END (but you may have several WHEN...). look at the help in the expression editor to get some proper syntax exemple

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose strings in single quotes, for example `'icn_ref'`.

And you can use `IN` operator:

```sql
CASE 
WHEN "network" IN('icn_ref','ncn','rcn') THEN '001|'
WHEN "network"='lcn_ref' THEN '002|'
ELSE ''
END
```

[image]